# Git branch --format with %(if) and %(align)

Tags: git, git-branch

I wanted to improve the display of my `git branch` using `--format`

First I came up with a solution that copies the default format

```
git branch --format "%(if)%(HEAD)%(then)%(HEAD)%(color:green)%(else) %(end) %(refname:short)"
```

Then I wanted to build up on that, adding other infos to the right. I figured I could align them with %(align:...)

```
git branch --format "%(align:50,left)%(if)%(HEAD)%(then)%(HEAD)%(color:green)%(else) %(end)%(refname:short)%(end)AAA"
```

But the result is the following:

```
git branch --format "%(align:50,left)%(if)%(HEAD)%(then)%(HEAD)%(color:green)%(else) %(end)%(refname:short)%(end)AAA"
  testbranch1                                      AAA
  testbranch2                                      AAA
* testbranch3                                  AAA
```

Any use of `%(if)` will mess with the align. I guess the align function counts the characters printed inside the `%(if)%(HEAD)`, even if they are not displayed.

Any solution to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to get the `%(align:50,left) ... %(end)` and the `%(if) ... %(then) ... %(else) ... %(end)` constructs distinct, they don't mix well:

```
$ git branch --format "%(if)%(HEAD)%(then)%(HEAD)%(color:green)%(else) %(end)%(align:50,left)%(refname:short)%(end)AAA"
```